# HTTP to HTTPS redirects on Kubernetes v1.22 running in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a GCP cluster that was running on v1.21 and I have upgraded it to v1.22. There were some deprecated API calls that I was doing and I have managed to get rid of most of them but one.

```
$ kubent
2:02PM INF >>> Kube No Trouble `kubent` <<<
__________________________________________________________________________________________
>>> Deprecated APIs removed in 1.22 <<<
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KIND      NAMESPACE   NAME            API_VERSION                 REPLACE_WITH (SINCE)
Ingress   elastic     kibana-kibana   networking.k8s.io/v1beta1   networking.k8s.io/v1 (1.19.0)
__________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am pretty sure I have found where this is defined in my terraform scripts and I have tried to upgrade it following the release notes but to no avail.

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "nginx_frontend_config" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "networking.gke.io/v1beta1"
    "kind"       = "FrontendConfig"
    "metadata" = {
      "name"      = "nginx-frontend-config"
      "namespace" = kubernetes_namespace.nginx.metadata[0].name
    }
    "spec" = {
      "redirectToHttps" = {
        "enabled"          = true
        "responseCodeName" = "FOUND"
      }
      "sslPolicy" = google_compute_ssl_policy.default.name
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to upgrade the `apiVersion` from `.../v1beta1` to `.../v1` but I get the following error when running the terraform scripts:

```
╷
│ Error: Failed to determine GroupVersionResource for manifest
│
│   with kubernetes_manifest.nginx_frontend_config,
│   on nginx.tf line 83, in resource "kubernetes_manifest" "nginx_frontend_config":
│   83: resource "kubernetes_manifest" "nginx_frontend_config" {
│
│ cannot select exact GV from REST mapper
╵
```

I have looked everywhere and I couldn't find a resource on how to define a Http -> Https redirect in Kubernetes v1.22. The official [guides on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#https_redirect) are referencing only the `v1beta1` version. And in the [Ingress Migration Guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#ingress-v122) it states to use the `v1` version but that doesn't work for me.

P.S. I have also tried `networking.k8s.io/v1` but it comes back with  `no matches for kind "FrontendConfig" in group "networking.k8s.io"` when I run the terraform scripts.

How do I define a `FrontendConfig` for a redirect post v1.22?

Comment: I'm also running into this exact issue now that I've upgraded my cluster to 1.22. Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: @rjkowalewski yes, basically this is a networking.gke.io resource and not networking.k8s.io so it doesn't need to be upgraded to v1 as gke.io will still be serving the v1beta1 version.